# How to delete Owin Token?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, owin

I have tried to delete by SignOut but it is not deleted or expire.

```
var authentication = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;

authentication.SignOut(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                              Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
                              Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie,
                              Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie);

        authentication.SignOut(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        authentication.SignOut(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        authentication.SignOut();
```

I tried to find solution in many blog (msdn, stack overflow etc.) but not yet seen the solution.

I am generating token by:

```
// Set claim
var identityType = new GenericIdentity(userName, Config.Constants.BASICIDENTITYTYPE);
string[] roles = null;
var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identityType, roles);
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;

if (HttpContext.Current != null)
{
    HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
}

var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(StartUp.OAuthBearerOptions.AuthenticationType);
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName));
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(Config.Constants.USERNAME, userName));
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(Config.Constants.USERID, userId.ToString()))

// Generate ticket
AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, new AuthenticationProperties());

var currentUtc = new SystemClock().UtcNow;
ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = currentUtc;

TimeSpan expiryTime = Constants.TOKEN_EXPIRY_TIME_SECOND);
ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = currentUtc.Add(expiryTime);

return StartUp.OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'Owin Token'? The session Cookie?

Comment: @Brent Schmaltz I want Delete or Expire Owin Token.

Comment: What does your startup.cs look like?

Comment: @Brent Schmaltz: Added in question part about how i generate token. Thank you Brent  for reading..

Answer (score 0):

Within the simplest Identity configuration try:

```
Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();
```

it should do the job

Hope this helps.